# Enable disabled functionality is not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I am trying to enable/disable Magento 2 from admin general setting.
I created an option to disabled / enabled module from backend > configuration > module > enable (Yes/No)

when I tried to disabled module functionality still working.
Is it a database related issue or another issue.

Secondly, I tried to get check in coding whether module enable or not by followed below steps

**Index controller :-**

```
<?php  
namespace Vender\Modulename\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
   {
      protected $resultJsonFactory;
      protected $scopeConfig;

      public function __construct(Context $context, 
      \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
     \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory)
        {
           $this->resultJsonFactory  = $resultJsonFactory;
         //$this->_helper = $helper;
           $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
           parent::__construct($context);
        }
      protected function helper($className) 
      {
         return $this->_objectManager->get($className);
       }

      protected function getUrl($path) 
     {
      return $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface')->getUrl($path);
      }

     public function execute()
     {
    //die('dfsd');
    //$topTel = $this->_helper->getConfig('dynamicpdf/general/topTel');
    //$_thishepler = $this->_helper('Vender\Modulename\Helper\Data');
    //$isEnabled = $helper->getStoreConfig('VenderMOdulename/general/enabled');
    //print_r($isEnabled); die;
    $helper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Vendor\modulename\Helper\Data');

    echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($helper);

    if($helper->isEnable()){
    }
          // My code
  }

}
```

**Helper > Data.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
   protected $context;

   public function __construct(Context $context)
   {
       $this->context = $context;
       parent::__construct($context);
   }

   public function isEnable()
   {
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('modulename/general/enable', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of System.xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you **enabled/disabled** one or more modules, then you will need to run magento `setup:upgrade` to update the database schema.

Try running commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento c:c
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your **Index Controller** file.

```
protected $helperData;

public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Modulename\Helper\Data $helperData
) {
    $this->helperData = $helperData;
}
```

then use below code to call your helper function.

```
$this->helperData->isEnable();
```

**EDIT:** in your helper file you didn't declare variable

```
protected $scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
)
{
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}
```

This is the proper way to call helper function/method instead using Object Manager.

Don't forget to flush cache.

Comment: if($this->helperData->isEnable()){
            echo "enabled";
  }else{
  echo "not enbaled";
  }

Comment: every time echo not enable

Comment: I thing data is not coming from helper > Data.php

Comment: I have seen every time it print 1

Comment: check my updated answer and edit your helper file to declare `scopeConfig` variable

Comment: I tried with edit answer, no out put in the index controller